# Editing cells of a table in R

Tags: r, datatable, edit

Is there a simple way in R to edit cells of a table while it is in view?
Might be something along 'edit' or 'fix'.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `edit(df)` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. How can I make the edit permanent?

Answer (score 1):

Try this native R function

```
utils::edit()
```